# Error at launching eclipse

Tags: runtime-error

everyone!
I have recently set up an Ubuntu partition on my laptop, and installed the open-jdk version "11.0.4". Afterwards, I "apt-got" eclipse straight from the Ubuntu repo, but on startup I get error whose related log file I'll report here:

```
!SESSION Mon Oct 14 22:47:33 CEST 2019 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-10-14 22:47:33.739
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I cannot even create my workspace. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and sorry if this results in a low quality post.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this type of error.

If you tried to install plugins without administrator permissions then it may cause this issue at the next time launching.

I have started my eclipse with "Start as administrator" and it automatically solved the issue itself and then opened Eclipse.